# laravel api ajax form wont submit

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, forms, api

This is my first api project. Can you help me with my code please?

I can't see the problem.

Here is my controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
   $valid=Validator::make($request->all(),[
      'text'=>'required',
      'body'=>'required'
   ]);

   if($valid->fails()){
       return response()->json(['message'=>$valid->messages()]);
   }else{

    $item= Item::create([
        'text'=>$request->input('text'),
        'body'=>$request->input('body')
    ]);
    return response()->json($item);
   }
}
```

and here is my form.Is there anything wrong in the form?

```
<form id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Text :</label>
            <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control col-sm-4">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Body :</label>
            <textarea id="body" class="form-control col-sm-4"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-action">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the ajax code between the show function is working but I don't know where  the problem is ?.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();//prevent the form to submit to file
        let text = $('#text').val();
        let body = $('#body').val();
        addItems(text, body);
    });


    function addItems(text, body) {
        var item = {
            text: text,
            body: body
        };
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/items',
            data: item,
            success: function (item) {
                alert('done the item number' + item.id + ' has been added!!');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error')
            }
        })
    }
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

if your front-end source separated from back-end source, then add [cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)
package to your laravel project.

if its on your laravel view then add csrf token to meta tag -
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

and send it with your ajax request `{ _token : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content}`

Comment: i already added the package .. i dont know what is the problem

Comment: check both.
1. in ajax error function check `console.log(error)` for debugging error
2. or check on network tab of [chrome browser](https://ibb.co/cQzKnz).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're sending the form without sending the cross site request forgery token.
Add the directive @csrf to your view
Then send it has Hasan wrote ;)

Comment: but my view is in different location and its html file .. how to add the csrf ? sorry im still learning can u show me how pls ?